# how to Design Rule Check an Eagle file in a git hook?

Tags: eaglecad

I can't find how to launch the ERC and DRC from the command line in Eagle. My hope is putting the command in a git pre-commit hook.

I'm perfectly ok with using a third party program or library if need be, but my google fu is not strong enough to find a useful tool.

Comment: Is it even possible to invoke eagle commands from command line?

Comment: The lack of information is hinting it is not possible (I might be wrong though).

Comment: I'm pretty sure they answer is no. Eagle tools can't be run from the command line.

Comment: Well, I came to ask here after my searches came empty, I'm looking for something a bit hard to find or inexistant.

Comment: There's an [EAGLE Automation](https://github.com/guyzmo/eagle-automation) project on Github. Seems they don't support this (yet), but you could open an issue and suggest this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can execute commands from the cmd in windows when i browse to :[eagle-path]\bin. Tried with eagle 5 and 7.5.
The command for ERC is
eagle -C "erc;" [your schematic.sch]

When i remember correctly than -C is for command.

The help section found in the installation directory or in the gui is your friend here. You are searching for commando options.

Comment: Yes, but if I'm not wrong the command is **eagle -C "drc"**.

Comment: well, I had forgotten this question and found the answer a few weeks later. It must be noted that eagle is the shittiest command line program around, it will just open the GUI and show you the list, no way to export the list automatically. And the DRC only applies to the visible layers.